# Video pause if application goes in pause state while using youtube Video Player API in android app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Video pause if application goes in pause state while using youtube Video Player API in android my app.
But in youtube android app different behaviour. it keep playing video even in app in pause state.
Is it possible to provide same support in youtube sdk for android app develoment

I am using Multiwindow

```
Case 1# Two application is opne in Multiwindow Mode 
     1-youtube
     2-conatct 
when I tap on conatct app youtube is in pause state and conatct app is in
resume state still youtube video kepp playing

Case 2# Two application is opne in Multiwindow Mode 
     1-MyApp(with Youtube API)
     2-conatct 
when I tap on conatct app MyApp is in pause state and conatct app is in
resume state still MyApp video stop playing.

So My application is in pause state and vsisible.

So how to handle myapp so it will work like case #1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't provide a lot of information, but here are the different scenarios that can happen.

**Case 1: Activity paused and not visible**

Playing a YouTube video when the video itself is not visible (meaning: playing the audio of the video) is against YouTube terms of service. Audio and video cannot be separated.
Therefore playing a video when the Activity is not visible is not possible with the official video player API.

You can do it with this library: [Android-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player). It allows you to decide when and where you want to pause or play your videos.

But again, even if you can do it, doesn't mean you should. Separating audio and video is against YouTube terms of services, so you won't be able to publish your app on the PlayStore.

**Case 2: Activity paused and visible**

If the case you care about is when the Activity is paused but at the same time visible, there's no problem. You can use the player you prefer, just change your code so that the video doesn't pause when the Activity pauses.

Comment: I have updated and explained my query. Please suggest

Comment: as I said: just change your code so that the video doesn't pause when the Activity pauses. Check if you're calling pause on your player somewhere. If not try to call play in the Activity onPause method.

If this doesn't work with the official player, I can assure you it does work with the library I suggested.